# Tableau server tried to activate but said command not found

Tags: tableau-api

Hello everyone i tried to activate tableau server but it said

```
tsm command not found
```

i tried to activate it with using command

```
tsm licenses activate -k myproductkey
```

Before i tried to run this command

```
sudo ./initialize-tsm --accepteula
```

and got this 'warning', i do't really get the 'warning' meaning of it maybe because my lack of english(?)

```
User 'root' has been selected as the user to add to the TSM authorized group, but
TSM does not allow root as a TSM-authorized user. You must either re-run this
script using 'sudo' while logged in as a normal user instead of root (most common
case), rerun this script with the '-a username' option to select a user other than
root to add to the group, or the '-g' flag to disable group addition completely
and add appropriate users to the group yourself. Canceling.
```

Why do i get this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the -a flag to specify a user to be added to the tsmadmin and tableau groups instead of the user running this script. If you are installing with the root account, the you must specify the -a flag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).